# Array inside a Struct in C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure out how to add an array into a struct... a struct of ints for example would look like this:

```
struct test{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} test = {0,1,2};
```

but if I want to have an array for example:

```
struct test{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int deck[52];
} test;
```

is this doable? the initialization of the deck (of cards) happens in a different function. when I do it like this, I don't get an error in the `struct` but I get it when I try to use it... for example if I do this `test.deck[i] = 1;` it gives me this error:

```
Error C2143 Syntax Error missing ';' before '.'
```

if I were to use `a` , I could write `test.a = 1;`

Could anyone write a simple struct where a variable in it is an array and then just use it for a simple command?

Comment: Please show a complete example of the failing code.

Comment: Why are you giving your variable the same identifier as it's type?

Comment: Yes, that is completely doable. I'm not sure why it's causing problems for you. Perhaps you can post more code.

Comment: The big problem I am having with posting the code is that for this problem to make sense I'd have to put a whole lot of code up here... that's why I asked if someone can just write an extremely basic example of initialization and usage, so I can compare

Comment: Your example works fine for me - what's your environment?

Comment: It works fine for me too, post a small example where the code fails and also try changing the name of your variable.

Answer (score 5):

If this is C++, no C, drop the test after the struct definition.

The following code works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int deck[52];
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test t;
    t.deck[1] = 1;
    cout << "t.deck[1]: "<< t.deck[1] << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

The problem:
 In C, you put the test *after* the definition to create a variable named test. So in C, test is *not* a type, it is a *global variable*, the way you wrote that.

This compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int deck[52];
} test;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test.deck[1] = 1;
    cout << "test.deck[1]: "<< test.deck[1] << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Your second example is exactly what the OP has in the question, isn't it?

Comment: The OP didn't post the code in which he uses the struct. And that, I think, may be wrong. Has he declared i before trying to index the vector? Well, he asked for an example of a code that would compile, I gave it to him.

Answer (score 3):

The error:

> Error C2143 Syntax Error missing ';' before '.'

is due to `test` being a type name. You need to define an instance:

```
int main() {
   test mytest;
   mytest.deck[1] = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: He did create an instance. It just happened to have the same name as the type, which was silly.